# How can I check if a script is compatible with AutoHotkey v2?

Tags: autohotkey, compatibility

I have a collection of scripts which was created with AutoHotkey v1. I would like check to see if these scripts are compatible with the upcoming [AutoHotkey v2](https://autohotkey.com/v2/).

According to the [changelog](https://autohotkey.com/v2/v2-changes.htm), there have been several changes in AutoHotkey v2 which break backwards compatibility with v1. This has made it hard to tell which scripts need updating without thorough testing.

Even after determining that a script needs to be updated, it can be even more difficult to determine which parts of the scripts need updating.

**How can I check if a script needs to be updated for compatibility with AutoHotkey v2?**

Comment: The answer to your question as it is currently phrased is "look at the change log" but it sounds like you want something more efficient than that. If so, please edit your question to specify exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

From what the notes suggest, you will be best piping the output to a file and checking the result.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe

> When parameters are passed to Ahk2Exe, a message indicating the success or failure of the compiling process is written to stdout. Although the message will not appear at the command prompt, it can be "caught" by means such as redirecting output to a file. [v1.0.43+]

```
Ahk2Exe.exe /in MyScript.ahk > MyScript.txt
```

To make things simpler, you could pipe all to the same file.

```
Ahk2Exe.exe /in MyScript.ahk >> Scripts.txt
```